# MySQL database corrupt when moving DirectAdmin user

Tags: mysql, database, directadmin

My hosting company has moved user `user1` to `user2` using DirectAdmin's tool for this (script built in DirectAdmin that basically shuts down MySQL, renames user folder, turns on MySQL).

After that they've imported a DirectAdmin back-up that was assigned to `user1`.

Now the database of `user2` got corrupted, I have got all the files (`.frm` and `.ibd` extension) but the hosting company cant get them to work. Unfortunately we dont have a recent back-up we can use.

What are my options on recovering this database? When I import it like this, it lists the tables in phpMyAdmin but I can't see its contents.

Comment: That's why you should take frequent backups. Without which chances of recovering is almost none.

Comment: I agree - this was my mistake. Daily back-ups are now enabled, but that's too late obviously.